# Looping through SQL Table valued function using query

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am trying to loop through a table valued function by passing parameters from a `select` query.

Example `fnDoSomething(Param1)`

This function returns a single row.

I am trying to run this against multiple parameters using a select query i.e. 
             `select param1 from table2.`

The end result I am trying to achieve should produce a table of rows from the function... something like:

row1 using first value of select query...
row2 using second value of select query
.
.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you please  elaborate and specify with an example

Comment: An example of the function code might be useful as well. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Sounds like a job for `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: I understand his question and I am looking for an answer too